# spawning sub worker returns error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-worker

I am spawnning child worker but it is throwing an error `"Worker not defined".`

how can I spawn child worker?

[Here is my demo getting error.](http://www.antkorp.in/childWorker/)

Comment: I am using chrome latest version(23).

Answer (score 3):

Until Chrome fixes this issue, you can use this [Subworker polyfill](https://github.com/dmihal/Subworkers) that I wrote

Answer (score 0):

Spawning subworkers is not supported in Chrome/Safari: have a look at the issue that has not be addressed yet: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31666